# VB.Net how to make a Key Selection Button

Tags: vb.net

Since my last post was incredibly informative, and people seemed to get the wrong idea of what I wanted to make, I figured I would do a detailed version here. In my last post, someone mentioned I should enter code, I would, I really would, issue is, I've been working on every way I can possibly think for the past day, scouring Google, writing things that make logical sense but don't, with no results, to the point that I just deleted all my code and decided to start fresh.
So here is the pseudo code of what I want to try and do.

1. The user has a button on their interface saying '< Click and Press >
2. They click the button and the button changes it's text to '< Press a Key! >'
3. They then push any key on the keyboard, let's use 'K' as an example, and the button then displays the Virtual Keycode of that key. That being '75' so the button would display '75'.
4. This then gets stored in a variable where it can later be exported to a TXT document. (I know how to do this part for the most of it.)

I hope that sort of clears up some of the confusion that happened in my last post.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of pages that might help...

[`Control.KeyUp` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)
[`KeyEventArgs` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)